# sequelize migration not working

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

I created a migration and ran it.  It says it worked fine, but nothing happened.  I don't think it is even connecting to my database.

### My Migration file:

```
var util = require("util");
module.exports = {
up : function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    
migration.createTable('nameOfTheNewTable', {
    attr1 : DataTypes.STRING,
    attr2 : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    attr3 : {
        type : DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue : false,
        allowNull : false
    }
}).success(
        function() {

            migration.describeTable('nameOfTheNewTable').success(
                    function(attributes) {
                        util.puts("nameOfTheNewTable Schema: "
                                + JSON.stringify(attributes));
                        done();
                    });

        });
},
down : function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    // logic for reverting the changes
}
};
```

### My Config.json:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pw",
    "database": "my-db",
    "dialect" : "sqlite",
    "host": "localhost"
  }
}
```

### The command:

```
./node_modules/sequelize/bin/sequelize --migrate --env development
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
Running migrations...
20130921234513-initial.js
nameOfTheNewTable Schema: {"attr1":{"type":"VARCHAR(255)","allowNull":true,"defaultValue":null},"attr2":{"type":"INTEGER","allowNull":true,"defaultValue":null},"attr3":{"type":"TINYINT(1)","allowNull":false,"defaultValue":false}}
Completed in 8ms
```

I can run this over and over and the output is always the same.  I've tried it on a database which I know to have existing tables and try to describe those tables and still nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

### EDIT:

I'm pretty sure I'm not connecting to the db, but try as I might I cannot connect using the migration.  I can connect using `sqlite3 my-db.sqlite` and run commands such as `.tables` to see tables I have created previously, but I cannot for the life of me get the "nameOfTheNewTable" table created using a migration.  (I want to create indexes in the migration too).  I have tried using **"development"**, changing values in the `config.json` like the host, database (my-db, ../my-db, my-db.sqlite), etc.

Here's a good example, in the `config.json` I put `"database" : "bad-db"` and the output from the migration is exactly the same.  When it is done, there is no bad-db.sqlite file to be found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the 'storage' parameter in your config.json, so that sequelize knows what file to use as the sqlite DB.

Sequelize defaults to using memory storage for sqlite, so it's migrating an in-memory database, then exiting, effectively destroying the DB it just migrated.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense.

Answer (score 1):

you most likely have to wait for `migration.createTable` to finish:

```
migration.createTable(/*your options*/).success(function() {  
    migration.describeTable('nameOfTheNewTable').success(function(attributes) {  
        util.puts("nameOfTheNewTable Schema: " + JSON.stringify(attributes));  
        done()  
    });
})
```

Comment: Good point.  Updated my code to use the success callback.  The output has changed, but the table is still not created.

Comment: It looks like there is no way for migrations to know what file for sqlite to use, since the 'storage' parameter is not read from config.json.  I opened issue #1050 on github:  https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1050

Comment: I'm full of poop.  You just need to specify the 'storage' parameter.